# Dockerfile start jboss cli fails

Tags: maven, docker, jboss, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I want to start the docker-cli.sh script on Wildfly.

```html
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.0.0.Final

COPY maven/config /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
COPY maven/deployments /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
COPY maven/postgres-module /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/org/postgresql/main/

RUN mkdir -p wildfly/modules/org/postgresql/main

RUN wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

RUN wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990


CMD ["wildfly/bin/standalone.sh","-b","0.0.0.0","-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

This is my docker file.
If I want to build it with (https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin) mvn docker:build , I face the following error:

The command 'wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990' returned a non-zero code: 1 -> [Help 1]

But if I comment, the second last line and execute it, it works.

If I after the container starts, connect with the docker cli with Kitemanic, I can execute this script step.

Error Log:

```html
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.21.0:build (default-cli) on project country_service: Unable to build image [company_service] : The command 'wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990' returned a non-zero code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.21.0:build (default-cli) on project country_service: Unable to build image [company_service] : The command 'wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990' returned a non-zero code: 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to build image [company_service] : The command 'wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990' returned a non-zero code: 1
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:226)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.DockerAccessException: Unable to build image [company_service] : The command 'wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990' returned a non-zero code: 1
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.hc.DockerAccessWithHcClient.buildImage(DockerAccessWithHcClient.java:220)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.service.BuildService.doBuildImage(BuildService.java:160)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.service.BuildService.buildImage(BuildService.java:124)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.service.BuildService.buildImage(BuildService.java:60)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.BuildMojo.buildAndTag(BuildMojo.java:58)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.BuildMojo.executeInternal(BuildMojo.java:44)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:223)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.DockerAccessException: The command 'wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9990' returned a non-zero code: 1
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.chunked.BuildJsonResponseHandler.process(BuildJsonResponseHandler.java:25)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.chunked.EntityStreamReaderUtil.processJsonStream(EntityStreamReaderUtil.java:26)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.hc.DockerAccessWithHcClient$HcChunkedResponseHandlerWrapper.handleResponse(DockerAccessWithHcClient.java:652)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.hc.ApacheHttpClientDelegate$StatusCodeCheckerResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApacheHttpClientDelegate.java:172)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:222)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.hc.ApacheHttpClientDelegate.post(ApacheHttpClientDelegate.java:102)
        at io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.hc.DockerAccessWithHcClient.buildImage(DockerAccessWithHcClient.java:218)
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker logs` for this container please?

Comment: @Fotis i add the error log

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution (was from a teammate):

```html
<run>
 <ports>
  <port>8080:8080</port>
  <port>9990:9990</port>
 </ports>
 <extraHosts>
      <extraHost>my_db_postgress:192.168.99.100</extraHost>
 </extraHosts>
</run>
```

I added to the run config an extra host, and add it to my standalone.xml